# Is there a way to receive notifications from specific questions updates?

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes, there are questions that let you really curious about what will be the final solution (if there is finally a solution). And I wonder if there is any way to subscribe to that question, and receive updates as they happen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can *favorite* questions (star icon under voting arrows) and [there is your *favorites* tab](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/users/39150/capiedge?tab=favorites) in your profile.

Though I don't think there is proactive option to have it email you or something, so you will probably just have to check it in profile now and then. It *will* track and show if any changes happened since last time you viewed the thread.

Comment: Ok @Rarst I didn't even knew about the favorite questions, my apologies. Perhaps a custom notifications digest could be a good improvement!

Comment: Nothing to apologize for, now you do. :)